# Best practices for maintaining assets accross (sub)domains?

Tags: php, html, apache, assets, subdomain

My webserver filesystem is equivalent to the following:

```
/master-domain.tld
/master-domain.tld/assets/js/foo.js
/master-domain.tld/assets/css/bar.css

/sub1.master-domain.tld
/sub1.master-domain.tld/assets/js/foo.js

/sub2.master-domain.tld
/sub1.master-domain.tld/assets/css/bar.css
...
```

What I'd like to know is how to serve my common static assets (hosted on the master domain) to my subdomains-- reason being that I then only have to maintain a single set of 'master' assets, rather than update/copy any files to all other subdomains each time I edit them. Obviously this can be achieved using absolute URLs, but my aim is to avoid these so that my local/dev system needn't make any remote calls while I'm designing/debugging.

Currently, I have a mod_rewrite + symbolic link + php script combo set up for each subdomain, linking any calls to non-existent local assets to the master assets. e.g. calling "/sub1.master-domain.tld/assets/css/bar.css" will retrieve the bar.css file hosted on the *master* domain since a local version of bar.css does not exist. Furthermore, calling "/sub1.master-domain.tld/assets/js/foo.js" would serve the *local* version of foo.js, since it does exist.

But my current method seems to be hindering the performance of my page loads, and I wonder if there is a better (still modular) approach to solving this problem.

Any tips? Am I going about this in completely the wrong way?

Answer (score 1):

Symbolic links should be all that's required if they're all on the same server.  This should cause no performance hits at all.  E.g.

```
/sub1.master-domain.tld/assets -> /master-domain.tld/assets
```

If your subdomains are served from multiple servers, I would set up a mod_rewrite rule with 302 redirects to the complete URL on the master domain.  On that master domain server I would set mod_expires so the assets are cached, avoiding most subsequent requests to the same "missing" assets on the subdomains.

Answer (score 0):

If they are on the same machine, why not point different virtual host aliases to the same document root?

Comment: Perhaps I'm misunderstanding, but I take it you mean to do something like this?:
`<VirtualHost *:80>  
    DocumentRoot "/path/to/master-domain.tld"  
    ServerName master-domain.tld  
    ServerAlias sub1.master-domain.tld  
</VirtualHost>`

But this wouldn't allow me to host the site itself on the subdomain... (since, AFAIK, I can't specify a specific file path within the ServerAlias statement). Unless you meant to use mod_alias instead--but that would essentially be equivalent to the symbolic links I have setup now, no?

Answer (score 0):

I'd use reserved static. subdomain for this purpose and aim all request on that one.

Comment: I believe this would be equivalent to using absolute URLs; I'd have to list file src's as follows:
`<script src="http://assets-sub.master-domain.tld/assets/js/foo.js"></script>`, which wouldn't fulfill my goal of being local/remote-host independent.